# vcap failed to open[udp @ 0x56378e8a76a0] bind failed: Permission denied

Tags: opencv, udp, ipv6

Im trying to use the VideoCapture function from opencv with an ipv6 address to stream from my raspberry pi to my debian virtual machine but I get the error in the title when I try.

I've confirmed that the ipv6 address is reachable with netcat and mplayer with the following:

Debian host machine:

netcat -l -6 -u 2222

raspberry pi:

/opt/vc/bin/raspivid -t 0 -w 300 -h 300 -hf -fps 20 -o - | nc -u (ipv6 address) 2222

Code:

```
    VideoCapture vcap;

     const string videoStreamAddress = "udp://" + "(my Ipv6 address)" + ":2222";

 vcap.open(videoStreamAddress);
```

edit: I've confirmed vcap.open works, with 127.0.0.1 but the problem is that it still doesnt work with my ipv6 address

Comment: Since you are using a port number, did you follow the RFC and enclose the IPv6 address in brackets?

Comment: thank you for telling me that exists, I put brackets in my ip address and now it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPv6 addresses used in the format you have specified, `<protocol>://`, are required to be enclosed in brackets (`[` and `]`). This was originally specified in *[RFC 2732, Format for Literal IPv6 Addresses in URL's](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2732.txt)* and continued in *[RFC 3896:, Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)*:

> **3.2.2. Host**
>
> The host subcomponent of authority is identified by an IP literal
> encapsulated within square brackets, an IPv4 address in dotted-
> decimal form, or a registered name. The host subcomponent is case-
> insensitive.  he presence of a host subcomponent within a URI does not
> imply that the scheme requires access to the given host on the
> Internet. In many cases, the host syntax is used only for the sake of
> reusing the existing registration process created and deployed for
> DNS, thus obtaining a globally unique name without the cost of
> deploying another registry. However, such use comes with its own
> costs: domain name ownership may change over time for reasons not
> anticipated by the URI producer. In other cases, the data within the
> host component identifies a registered name that has nothing to do
> with an Internet host.  We use the name "host" for the ABNF rule
> because that is its most common purpose, not its only purpose.
>
> ```
>   host        = IP-literal / IPv4address / reg-name
> ```
>
> The syntax rule for host is ambiguous because it does not completely
> distinguish between an IPv4address and a reg-name. In order to
> disambiguate the syntax, we apply the "first-match-wins" algorithm: If
> host matches the rule for IPv4address, then it should be considered an
> IPv4 address literal and not a reg-name.  Although host is
> case-insensitive, producers and normalizers should use lowercase for
> registered names and hexadecimal addresses for the sake of uniformity,
> while only using uppercase letters for percent-encodings.
>
> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6
> [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal
> within square brackets ("[" and "]"). This is the only place where
> square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax. In
> anticipation of future, as-yet-undefined IP literal address formats,
> an implementation may use an optional version flag to indicate such a
> format explicitly rather than rely on heuristic determination.
>
> ```
>   IP-literal = "[" ( IPv6address / IPvFuture  ) "]"
>
>   IPvFuture  = "v" 1*HEXDIG "." 1*( unreserved / sub-delims / ":" )
> ```
>
> The version flag does not indicate the IP version; rather, it
> indicates future versions of the literal format. As such,
> implementations must not provide the version flag for the existing
> IPv4 and IPv6 literal address forms described below. If a URI
> containing an IP-literal that starts with "v" (case-insensitive),
> indicating that the version flag is present, is dereferenced by an
> application that does not know the meaning of that version flag, then
> the application should return an appropriate error for "address
> mechanism not supported".
>
> A host identified by an IPv6 literal address is represented inside the
> square brackets without a preceding version flag. The ABNF provided
> here is a translation of the text definition of an IPv6 literal
> address provided in [RFC3513]. This syntax does not support IPv6
> scoped addressing zone identifiers.
>
> A 128-bit IPv6 address is divided into eight 16-bit pieces. Each piece
> is represented numerically in case-insensitive hexadecimal, using one
> to four hexadecimal digits (leading zeroes are permitted). The eight
> encoded pieces are given most-significant first, separated by colon
> characters. Optionally, the least-significant two pieces may instead
> be represented in IPv4 address textual format. A sequence of one or
> more consecutive zero-valued 16-bit pieces within the address may be
> elided, omitting all their digits and leaving exactly two consecutive
> colons in their place to mark the elision.
>
> ```
>   IPv6address =                            6( h16 ":" ) ls32
>               /                       "::" 5( h16 ":" ) ls32
>               / [               h16 ] "::" 4( h16 ":" ) ls32
>               / [ *1( h16 ":" ) h16 ] "::" 3( h16 ":" ) ls32
>               / [ *2( h16 ":" ) h16 ] "::" 2( h16 ":" ) ls32
>               / [ *3( h16 ":" ) h16 ] "::"    h16 ":"   ls32
>               / [ *4( h16 ":" ) h16 ] "::"              ls32
>               / [ *5( h16 ":" ) h16 ] "::"              h16
>               / [ *6( h16 ":" ) h16 ] "::"
>
>   ls32        = ( h16 ":" h16 ) / IPv4address
>               ; least-significant 32 bits of address
>
>   h16         = 1*4HEXDIG
>               ; 16 bits of address represented in hexadecimal
> ```
>
> A host identified by an IPv4 literal address is represented in
> dotted-decimal notation (a sequence of four decimal numbers in the
> range 0 to 255, separated by "."), as described in [RFC1123] by
> reference to [RFC0952]. Note that other forms of dotted notation may
> be interpreted on some platforms, as described in Section 7.4, but
> only the dotted-decimal form of four octets is allowed by this
> grammar.
>
> ```
>   IPv4address = dec-octet "." dec-octet "." dec-octet "." dec-octet
>
>   dec-octet   = DIGIT                 ; 0-9
>               / %x31-39 DIGIT         ; 10-99
>               / "1" 2DIGIT            ; 100-199
>               / "2" %x30-34 DIGIT     ; 200-249
>               / "25" %x30-35          ; 250-255
> ```
>
> A host identified by a registered name is a sequence of characters
> usually intended for lookup within a locally defined host or service
> name registry, though the URI's scheme-specific semantics may require
> that a specific registry (or fixed name table) be used instead. The
> most common name registry mechanism is the Domain Name System (DNS). A
> registered name intended for lookup in the DNS uses the syntax defined
> in Section 3.5 of [RFC1034] and Section 2.1 of [RFC1123]. Such a name
> consists of a sequence of domain labels separated by ".", each domain
> label starting and ending with an alphanumeric character and possibly
> also containing "-" characters.  The rightmost domain label of a fully
> qualified domain name in DNS may be followed by a single "." and
> should be if it is necessary to distinguish between the complete
> domain name and some local domain.
>
> ```
>   reg-name    = *( unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims )
> ```
>
> If the URI scheme defines a default for host, then that default
> applies when the host subcomponent is undefined or when the registered
> name is empty (zero length). For example, the "file" URI scheme is
> defined so that no authority, an empty host, and "localhost" all mean
> the end-user's machine, whereas the "http" scheme considers a missing
> authority or empty host invalid.
>
> This specification does not mandate a particular registered name
> lookup technology and therefore does not restrict the syntax of reg-
> name beyond what is necessary for interoperability. Instead, it
> delegates the issue of registered name syntax conformance to the
> operating system of each application performing URI resolution, and
> that operating system decides what it will allow for the purpose of
> host identification. A URI resolution implementation might use DNS,
> host tables, yellow pages, NetInfo, WINS, or any other system for
> lookup of registered names.  However, a globally scoped naming system,
> such as DNS fully qualified domain names, is necessary for URIs
> intended to have global scope. URI producers should use names that
> conform to the DNS syntax, even when use of DNS is not immediately
> apparent, and should limit these names to no more than 255 characters
> in length.
>
> The reg-name syntax allows percent-encoded octets in order to
> represent non-ASCII registered names in a uniform way that is
> independent of the underlying name resolution technology. Non-ASCII
> characters must first be encoded according to UTF-8 [STD63], and then
> each octet of the corresponding UTF-8 sequence must be percent-
> encoded to be represented as URI characters. URI producing
> applications must not use percent-encoding in host unless it is used
> to represent a UTF-8 character sequence. When a non-ASCII registered
> name represents an internationalized domain name intended for
> resolution via the DNS, the name must be transformed to the IDNA
> encoding [RFC3490] prior to name lookup. URI producers should provide
> these registered names in the IDNA encoding, rather than a
> percent-encoding, if they wish to maximize interoperability with
> legacy URI resolvers.